# How to recover messed up Eclipse/ADT project

Tags: android, eclipse

I was trying to look at the Build Path options for my current project but wound up doing something else.  I am not sure what happened, but something popped up on my screen and I had already hit enter expecting something else and the dialog went away and I have no idea what actually happened.  I immediately tried to "Undo" but the menu option was grayed out! After this, a red exclamation point popped up next to my project name in the package explorer, and a bunch of my resources seem messed up, for instance I see "res", "res.layout", "res.menu" and "res.values" at the top level, where I didn't before.  I also can no longer build the project, it tells me there are errors I need to fix first, but other than the "!" associated with the project itself, nothing has an indicator indicating something is wrong.

How can I fix this?

Update: I looked in my errors and found that for some reason it was referencing a directory with the name of a different project.  After I got rid of this it still doesn't want to compile, claiming `Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoVersionImpl;`

I also can't figure out how to fix my folders... it appears that my assets, bin, libs, and res folders all got turned into something else... they all now have icons which looks like a square target with a folder overlaid in the bottom-right quadrant, all in black and white.  It won't let me re-create these as folders, because the folders already exist, and when I try to move them to the right place (e.g. when I try to move libs.armeabi under libs) it wants me to rename it (e.g. to libs.armeabi.copy) which doesn't seem right.

Here's a screen shot of the folders after I made the red exclamation go away:
[image]

I tried removing the project from my workspace and re-importing it.  When I do this, I get a window saying "Multiple problems have occurred" building the workspace:

```
Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Android Pre Compiler' on project 'MyTest'.
Path must include project and resource name: /MyTest
```

Is it somehow thinking my project is relative to the root directory? (It's not!)

Comment: This seems like a build error that prevents the "R" file from being created or referenced. However, pictures are worth a thousand words - maybe post a screen shot?

Comment: FYI - the error you just added in your edit means that your path includes two libraries that define AccessibilityService in different ways... but that can be a project config problem, a path error or another error that leads doesn't fail but leads to this..

Comment: @Jim I just tried deleting the libs directory and re-creating it, but it still has the error (I'm just copy/pasting libs directly from another project that works) but it still won't display it properly as a folder.

Comment: It's been awhile since I used Eclipse, but first - restart it. Second, there may be a setting in Project Properties that specifies "source" that is missing the "src" directory

Comment: @Jim I looked around in all the directory setting without luck, but I managed to find a workaround... I created a brand new Eclipse project and just copied everything back in.

Answer (score 0):

You should follow these steps

- check your lib folder. Are there any duplicate jar filename or type?
    A. Same names (e.g 2 or more sampleLibrary.jar)
    B. Same library even different names (e.g facebooklibrary.jar and facebooklib.jar)
- Check your AndroidManifest.xml. Are there any duplicate naming?

  For example

  ```
  // other manifest xml stuff
  <TextView android:id="@+id/textview1"
      // any other textview stuff 
  />
  // more other manifest xml stuff
  <TextView android:id="@+id/textview1"
      // any other textview stuff 
  />
  ```
- Check your other xml files for duplicate naming like manifest xml

"Duplicate definition" is what did you get error message.